# Django project requirements missing after Ubuntu Jellyfish update

Tags: django, ubuntu

After updating Ubuntu to the latest update, Pycharm tells me required packages are missing but the virtual environment is activated and the packages are all there.

Trying to `runserver` results in `ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

Trying to install packages again results in `Invalid Python SDK`

Anyone having this problem after the update? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Creating a new `venv` seems to be a simply and fool-proof solution.

When using `python3` it used the python at locate at `/usr/bin/python3` instead of `/venv/bin/python3`.

It behaves like the `venv` isn't activated, while it actually is.
The venv directory in the project is immutate but it seems like Pycharm doesen't recognize it.

Looking at the interpreter seems like no package is installed or can be installed (both with gui or cli).

In the case this is a commonly experienced problem, please use this question for further investigations.

Comment: Could you verify which python are you using by running `which python3` ?

Comment: the output is /usr/bin/python3 the version is 3.9

Comment: What happens if you use python binary in your virtual environment `<virtual-env-path>/bin/python3 manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: python3 in venv/bin is an invalid symlink, it doens't run.. didn't notice this

Comment: try to recreate your virtual environment, but run this command first `python3 -m pip --user virtualenv` https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-virtualenv

Comment: yes creating a new venv from scratch solves the problem, but I was interested in investigate why the new Ubuntu update causes problems with previous venvs.

Answer (score 0):

As the exact Python version and the paths to the system libraries might change with the update, the created venvs might also break.

Therefore, it is always recommended to recreate all venvs after updating the system.